# VBA Cells.select copy paste not bringing images over consistantly

Tags: vba, excel, copy, paste

I have some data and some images on a sheet.
I have some code that copies the data & images from this sheet in one workbook to a sheet in another workbook.

The problem:  it seems to be hit or miss if it will bring over the images. Sometimes they copy, sometimes they don't WTF?

```
            wb.Sheets(form).Activate
            wb.Sheets(form).Cells.Select
            Selection.Copy
            objwbk.Activate
            ws.Range("A1").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Still not working if anyone wants the credit for helping me with this..

Comment: I have figured out that it won't copy objects on some peoples computers because the new workbook that is being made opens in "compatibility" mode" for some reason. No idea how to prevent that.

Answer (score 4):

Set

```
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
```

Before copying

BTW your code

```
wb.Sheets(form).Activate
wb.Sheets(form).Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
objwbk.Activate
ws.Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

will reduce to:

```
Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
wb.Sheets(form).Cells.Copy ws.Range("A1")
```

Comment: added your line. Objects seem to copy using my computer but when I run the macro from my co-workers computer the objects don't copy over.. :(

Comment: Does the workbook you're pasting into have any kind of event handlers?

Comment: I don't think so, it's just a new workbook with a new sheet created and this stuff pasted into it.

Comment: Sorry - I don't know what else to suggest: adding that line always resolved that problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I am creating a new book and pasting to the new book but it's in compatibility modes solve below

```
'Remember the users setting which currently is 97-2003 file format
SaveFormat = Application.DefaultSaveFormat
 'Set it to the 2007-2010 file format xlsm
Application.DefaultSaveFormat = 52

'MAKE NEW BOOK HERE

 'Set DefaultSaveFormat back to the users setting
Application.DefaultSaveFormat = SaveFormat
```

Answer (score 0):

late (ok.. very late ..) answer but i've got the same problem today.

I've try to open the source workbook in read-only mode and it works for for me ™.

So, when you set your objwbk (somethink like set objwbk = open("c:\path\wbk.xls",,true) ) put the third argument to true.